# Removing a missing project from a solution in Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

My solution is stored in Visual Studio Online and, for some reason, every time I go to check it in, I am asked to check in a non-existing project called "ClassLibrary1". This project is neither listed on my Project Dependencies nor on my Build Order or Workspaces, it only shows up on my Team Explorer tab under "Included Changes". I have searched for the solution but maybe I am not using the right keywords. Can anybody tell me how to remove it so it won't show up on my solution's "Included Changes"?

Comment: Have you tried mapping a clean workspacing and doing a get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the folder and "undo pending changes".

The files are still on disk, even though you have removed them from the solution. Another option would be to go to the folder for your solution (right click on the solution and select Opens folder...') and remove the files manually.

Comment: Thanks! Just would like to add that the folder can be found under "Solutions" in "Team Explorer - Home".